# How to extract key, value pairs from struct column

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, struct

In Spark, I am trying to extract the key-value pairs within a struct column (that has structs as well).

It looks like this:

| column_1 |
| --- |
| {"key1": ["value1", "apple"], "key2": {"key3": "banana", "key4": {"key5": 12345, "key6": 23456, "key7": null, "key8": 54321}}} |

The schema of this data frame:

[image]

What I need is to access nested dictionary `key4`, and get all the key-value pairs from it. I tried to do that, using this code:

```py
def test_function(column_1):
  lst=[]
  test_dict=column_1['key2']['key4'].items()
  if test_dict is not None:
    for item in test_dict:
      lst.append(str(item))
  return(test_dict)
        
test_function_udf = udf(test_function)

dataframe.withColumn('get_output',test_function_udf('column_1')).select('column_1','get_output').display()
```

But it results into this error:

> PythonException: 'AttributeError: items'

How to get the key-value pairs?

I also tried this UDF:

```
def test_function(column_1):
  lst=[]
  test_dict=column_1['key2']['key4']
  for item in test_dict:
    lst.append(item)
  return(lst)
      
test_function_udf = udf(test_function)

aniProcessed.withColumn('test_xml',test_function_udf('column_1')).select('column_1','test_xml').display()
```

This at least helps me get the values of the dictionary, but what I more urgently need are the keys (rather than the values)

Comment: use pandas library

Comment: to access the nested struct, you can use dot notation and use * to select/flatten all sub structs. `df.select('column_1.key2.key4.*')`

Comment: Both suggestions are useful. But due to the size of this dataset, using Pandas would be no option - as it takes too much memory. The suggestion to flatten the sub structs, yes indeed that would solve this issue as well. But for this particular case, I would like to understand specifically why I am not able to read this sub struct as a dictionary.

Comment: In the first code, `column_1['key2']['key4']` returns Row object, so it doesn't have dict's function `items()`.  You need to do `...['key4'].asDict()` to get Python dictionary.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Row.asDict.html

Comment: That last suggestion worked for me and enables me to get the keys. I wasn't familiar with the "asDict()" function. I thought that when reading dataframes containing structs, the structs would automatically be red as dictionaries. Thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by user Emma above, the solution to this was easier than I actually hoped for. A simple addition of `asDict()` worked for me in order to solve this problem. Full block of code that I finally used is:

```
  lst=[]
  test_dict=column_1['key2']['key4'].asDict().items()
  if test_dict is not None:
    for item in test_dict:
      lst.append(str(item))
  return(test_dict)
```

The problem was that the object I wanted to iterate through was read as a Row object and therefore needed to be turned into a dictionary again.

Comment: I can but I will have to wait until tomorrow before mark my answer as accepted;-)